# jQuery UI Autocomplete dividing terms into separate characters, not words

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC site where I'm trying to **implement an autocomplete function using the jQuery UI autocomplete feature**.

Here's how my page is setup:

I have a textbox with id `TagInput`. Next, I have the following inline Javascript code:

```
$().ready(function () {
            bindAutoTagComplete('#TagInput');
        });
```

In addition to referencing the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries on that page, I also reference this external Javascript code:

```
function bindAutoTagComplete(item, otherRootDomain)
{
var url = (otherRootDomain || "") + "/tags/ajaxList";
        function split( val ) {
            return val.split(' ');
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
            return split( term ).pop();
        }

        $(item).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON(url, {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( " " );
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Everything works fine, except that the AJAX result with tag names is divided into single characters, not words.** For example, if I have two tags "foo" and "bar" that are returned, the autocomplete list that pops up lists:

- f
- o
- o
- b
- a
- r

instead of:

- foo
- bar

I've debugged the code, but haven't found **what is causing this incorrect division. Any ideas?** *Thanks in advance.*

**UPDATE:** Here's a sample of what's currently being returned by the server in that AJAX request:

> "foo bar some-other-tag"

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample of the json result that is being returned from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your tips, guys! I found the problem; in fact, there were two:

1. My application was returning the AJAX result in **incorrect format**. Based on the jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation, I have changed it to the correct format.
2. My AJAX call was sending the tag name as the **wrong parameter**, too.

It works now!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most probably the `split` function which looks like it's some custom split function. It's hard to say since there's not all relevant code here.